# Database in BlackBerry 10

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10, cascade

I want to learn database concept in BlackBerry 10 . I am referring BlackBerry's docs but didn't get the correct link . Can anyone give me link so that I can learn from it ?

Answer (score 4):

This code will guide u properly,

https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/databasecreation

https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/databasecrud

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one to create the DB connection:
https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/qsqldatabase.html#details

and this one for the queries:
https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/qsqlquery.html#details